# Next image without refreshing the whole page (on click)

Tags: html, onclick, refresh

Hi all am trying to "on click" go to the next image (I'll post code it will be easyer to understand what am trying to do)

```
  <form id="selector">
         <select onchange="initChapSelector();"></select>
         <select onchange="initPageSelector();"></select>
         <select onchange="initDisplay();"></select>
         </select>
  </form>
         <a href="#" onclick="moveToNextPage(); return false;"><img id="display" src="js/VKmanga/spinner.gif"></a>
```

but the only way I know is `href="#"` but that just refreshes the whole page
Is there any other ways I can make this work?

Am new to html/php so please forgive me if this above code is all wrong
Thanks

Also am working in a forum template if that means anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, href="#" should not refresh the whole page. Are you sure there aren't errors in moveToNextPage()?
You could also try javascript:void(0) in the href="...": it should do absolutely nothing.

Comment: I think its something to do with the forum am working in, As it keeps taking me back to the home page. example

/index.php?manga/ is where I have this code
keeps forcing me back to /

Comment: Yea its on localhost so can't give that out

Comment: So please create a standalone HTML/javascript testcase I can try. More, did href="javascript:void(0)" solve the problem?

Comment: Is there a way to stop it jumping to the top of the page on click?

http://dev.animelon.com/manga/ this is what ive been working on   Thanks again

Comment: The script you're using (http://dev.animelon.com/js/VKmanga/view.js) uses document.location.hash to perform the change between the images of the manga. This is the cause of the "scroll to top" behavior. I'm a decent javascript programmer but I know document.location.hash very little, I never used it. However, I could write the "image swap" thingie with absolutely no effort, and w/o scrolling up the page. That script seems too way complicated. See for example: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/13653

Comment: Yea it pulls all my images from the folders etc... oh well its ok I'll just live with it like this. Thanks so much for your help